# How do I change where Overwatch screenshots are saved?

Tags: overwatch

[According to Blizzard](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/200569), Overwatch screenshots taken with <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> are saved in `%UserProfile%/Documents/Overwatch/ScreenShots/Overwatch`.

Is there any way to change this to a more convenient folder like `%UserProfile%/Pictures` or `/Dropbox/Screenshots/Overwatch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is a way to change the path of where screenshots are saved.  I can't find a definitive source saying you can't, but for many other Blizzard games, it seems impossible.  There are a few work arounds:

1. You can create a shortcut to that folder.  Simply right click it, and create a shortcut.  Then, place that shortcut on your desktop, or somewhere that's more convenient.  You'll be taken right to the folder when you use the shortcut. This won't fix the issue of actually saving the screenshots somewhere else though.
2. You can try what [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4r2691/screenshots_and_how_to_change_the_location/) suggests and use a symbolic link.  They link to a guide found on [howToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) on how to do this. I'll attempt to summarize it:

   - Delete the Overwatch folder that the screenshots get saved to. Make sure you backup anything in there you want to keep!
   - Open a Command Prompt running as administrator.  If you are on Windows 10, and have developer mode enabled (and are updated to the latest version of Windows), you should be able to open a normal command prompt
   - Type `mklink` and press enter.  This will give you a list of the valid command parameters
   - For this, you will want to create a symbolic link.  To do so, the command to use is `mklink /D Link Target` where `Link` is the folder you want to link the original folder to, and the `Target` is the original folder.  You will need the full file path name for each.  If there are any spaces in any of the folder names, you must surround the entire path in double quotes
   - Make sure to name the symbolic link folder to Overwatch, otherwise it may not work.

From what I understand, a symbolic link folder is basically a pointer of some sort, and when a file gets placed in the folder, it's automatically moved to the symbolic link folder instead.  The article also contains another way of doing this using a graphical tool called [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html), should you find the command prompt way difficult.

Using that tool, it looks fairly simple.  Once you install it, basically right click the Overwatch folder and select "Pick Link Source."  After that, navigate to the folder you want to redirect the screenshots to and right click it.  A new option called "Drop As..." should be in the list of options.  Hover over it, and select "Symbolic Link."  This should do  the same thing as the command prompt stuff above.

Comment: When I put the destination folder as `Link`, Cmd says "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." I moved the screenshots folder to the intended destination folder. Cmd says `Link` specifies the new symbolic link name. So I put Overwatch like you said otherwise it may not work. It says, "Symbolic link created for Overwatch C:\Users\User\Documents\Overwatch\ScreenShots\Overwatch symbolic link created for Overwatch <<==>> C:\Users\User\Documents\Overwatch\ScreenShots\Overwatch". I don't see anything where the original folder used to be.